# Why are conditional events in Lit not working?

Tags: javascript, lit

The following code renders with no event handlers attached.  I've verified that this.evchange and/or this.evinput are true.  The events work if I set them up more verbosely.  But from reading the Conditionals section in the docs, this should work.

`` let evc = (this.evchange) ? html`@change=${this._changed}` : ''; ``

`` let evi = (this.evinput) ? html`@input=${this._changed}` : ''; ``

`` return html`${this.flabel} <input .value=${this.fvalue} ${evc} ${evi}>`; ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `html` tag function needs to contain [well-formed](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#well-formed-html) HTML. So it is not valid for the template to just contain an event binding.

To conditionally add event binding, you should should add the conditional within the expression and return `nothing` for falsy cases like:

```js
import {nothing} from 'lit';

return html`
  <input
    .value =${this.fvalue}
    @change=${this.evchange ? this._changed : nothing}
    @input=${this.evinput ? this._changed : nothing}
  >
`;
```